# Validity of JavaScript Type Parameters?

Tags: javascript, oop

Recently I stumbled across that JavaScript allows you to pass an object or array as the key to an object parameter. ex:

```
var myType = { 'Name':'MyType' };
var myObject = {};
myObject[myType] = 1;
```

will make `myObject[myType];` return `1`
From looking further into this, it seems like internally the object's `.toString()` method is being called and passed as the actual key. In the above example this actually breaks apart as that means what is really happening is `myObject['[object Object]']` is being set, meaning that any standard object passed in would access the same key.

However, I decided to expand upon this by creating custom objects which would cause their `.toString()` method to instead return their constructor. This would mean that it would return a unique key for each object type. Based on this, I created the following example of using this technique to create relatively clean implementation of a type parameter:

```
function Cat() {}
function Dog() {}

function AnimalPack() {
    this.speech = "";
    this.size = 0;
}

AnimalPack[Cat] = function() {
    var pack = new AnimalPack();
    pack.speech = "mew";
    pack.size = 2;
    return pack;
}

AnimalPack[Dog] = function() {
    var pack = new AnimalPack();
    pack.speech = "bark";
    pack.size = 4;
    return pack;
}

AnimalPack.prototype.Speak = function() {
    var speak = [];
    for(var i=0; i<this.size; i++) {
        speak.push(this.speech);
    }
    return speak.join(" ");
}

var catparty = new AnimalPack[Cat]();
var dogparty = new AnimalPack[Dog]();
```

In this example `catparty.Speak()` will return `'mew mew'` and `dogparty.Speak()` will return `'bark bark bark bark'`.

This could be used with native JavaScript types as well (String, Number, etc).

This seems to work standard across all 5 major browsers (chrome, firefox, ie, safari, opera).

I was wondering if there is some glaring flaw that I am not seeing in this technique, or if this is perhaps a valid way of implementing a type parameter?

Thanks!

Comment: The instanceof operator can also be very useful for testing types: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Comment: I have used instanceof before when I needed it. I thought of this technique to possibly get similar functionality to the `MyClass<T>` semantics of type parameters in other languages.

Comment: Interesting. What would be a use case for this?

Comment: @Ben The point of type-parameters in other languages is to allow expressing "generic" things in a strong/static type-system. It is not really practical in JavaScript which is a dynamic type-system. In this case it looks more like trying to get specification.

Comment: Yeah, I had generics mostly in mind when I was looking at this. While it probably wouldn't be very useful for native types as they are dynamically typed. I thought it might be something useful if you want more of a generic of custom types.

It's definitely not a new functionality, as instanceof easily accomplishes the same thing. Just possibly a different way of structuring/implementing it that might be handy in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do it that way. You can try this instead:

```
/function ([^(]*)/g.exec(dog.constructor)[1]
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XFdrd/)